# Best Practice for updating a SQL Compact database on a client

Tags: sql-server-ce, windows-phone-8, windows-store-apps

So most apps at some point will get changes. If you develop a client app with a SQL Compact database, and need to make structure changes (add a table, add a column, etc...) what are some tips or practices for doing so.

I'm thinking about mobile apps, Windows Phone, Windows RT/Store, etc.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows Phone you should use the [DatabaseSchemaUpdater](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.data.linq.databaseschemaupdater%28VS.95%29.aspx) - MS has a walkthrough for updating schema [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394022%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) as well.

Unfortunately for Windows Store apps, [it doesn't look like there will be SQL CE available.](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/f71c518c-c288-459e-917f-52b9cf8442d7) There is [SQLite](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2012/05/20/using-sqlite-in-metro-style-app.aspx) though.